# Put CSS Content inside tag <style amp-custom> for Wordpress

Tags: theme-development, hooks

I just want to put the CSS's content inside tag <style amp-custom>

#### This is my action inside function

```
function amp_template_add_styles() {
    $stylesheets = get_template_directory_uri() . '/material/public/app.min.css';
    echo file_get_contents( $stylesheets );
}
add_action( 'amp_template_css', 'amp_template_add_styles', 99 );
```

#### And i call the function insider tag <head>

```
<style amp-custom>
    <?php do_action( 'amp_template_css', 'amp_template_add_styles'); ?>
</style>
```

#### And this is the error when i implement in this way

[image]

There are anyone knows about this, please help me, thanks

Comment: why do you trying to include stylesheet in this way? cant you use enqueue method?

Comment: Google AMP need to put CSS inside tag <style amp-custom> and if you use wp_enqueue_style, u can't put it inside <style amp-custom>

Comment: function amp_template_add_styles() {
 ob_start();

    $stylesheets = file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/material/public/app.min.css');

 ob_clean();
    echo $stylesheets;
}
add_action( 'amp_template_css', 'amp_template_add_styles', 99 );

Comment: awesome, thank you so much

Comment: @Bhupen – Please consider adding a proper answer.